# While creating object of IExternalSignature, it is not working in Windows 7's win service(WAS). But same code working in windows 8

Tags: c#, itext, x509certificate2

```
IExternalSignature externalSignature = 
    new X509Certificate2Signature(certClient, "SHA-1");



Exception Occurred : 
            An internal error occurred.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.X509Certificate2Signature..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate, String hashAlgorithm)
   at WindowsService_HostAPI.ValuesController.Post(SignPDF pdfin) in E:\Aditya share\Harshit\WindowsService_HostAPI IGR Set Up\WindowsService_HostAPI\ValuesController.cs:line 587
Source : mscorlib
```

Comment: What library are you using? BouncyCastle?

Comment: yes, using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

Comment: It looks like it's failing trying to get hold of the key pair. Probably a permissions issue. The service user needs to have read permission to the key container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=service+permissions+private+key

Comment: I am using USB token(DSC), so can't access private key directly

Comment: Have you checked the application and Security event logs? They may have more detailed information.

Comment: Description: The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.The following information was included with the event: Get Digital Certificates Exception
the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

Comment: Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-09-24T12:22:41.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>15463</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>**********</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Get Digital Certificates Exception</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Comment: That event log looks like it was logged by your application. Is there an entry logged immediately before which might correspond to the underlying error? Maybe in the security or System log?

Comment: Anyway, have you confirmed that the service account has read permission on the key container?

Comment: Does the USB key even work? Maybe it's broken? You should check these things if you have not done so already.

Comment: yes, service account has read permission and as for the USB, its working fine in windows 8 and above

Comment: Time to break out the debugger.